# Discord.py | How to show on how many servers your bot is connected

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get it to show with the rest of the commands but it always gives a error about 'game' not being defined.

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle
from keep_alive import keep_alive

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=os.getenv('prefix'), intents=intents)
status = cycle(['nc.help', 'nc.streamers', 'nc.form'])
client.remove_command('help')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print(f"Sucessfully logged in as {client.user}")

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="on " + str(len(client.guilds)) + " Servers.", type=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`change_presence()`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=change_presence#discord.Bot.change_presence) does not have a `game` parameter replace it with `activity`

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="on " + str(len(client.guilds)) + " Servers.", type=0))
```